# could not load plugin assembly for type Cheesebaron.MvxPlugins.Settings.PluginLoader

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, mvvmcross

Please I am having the following problem Running my MVVMCross Application on a Windows Phone 8 Device

My Package Config is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Bulboss.MvvmCross.Plugins.UserInteraction" version="1.3.1" targetFramework="wp8" />
  <package id="Cheesebaron.MvxPlugins.Settings" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="wp8" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.9" targetFramework="wp8" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.14" targetFramework="wp8" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.22" targetFramework="wp8" />
  <package id="MvvmCross" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="wp8" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.Binding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="wp8" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.Core" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="wp8" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.Platform" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="wp8" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.Plugin.File" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="wp8" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.Plugin.Json" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="wp8" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.Plugin.Location" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="wp8" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.Plugin.Messenger" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="wp8" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.Plugin.Network" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="wp8" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.Plugin.Visibility" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="wp8" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.StarterPack" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="wp8" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="wp8" />
  <package id="WPtoolkit" version="4.2013.08.16" targetFramework="wp8" />
</packages>
```

I have the plugin bootstrapped as follows

```
 public class SettingsPluginBootstrap : MvxPluginBootstrapAction<Cheesebaron.MvxPlugins.Settings.PluginLoader>
    {

    }
```

And I use the Settings Plugin like so

```
public class SettingsService
    {

        private ISettings _settings;

        public SettingsService(ISettings settingsService)
        {
            _settings = settingsService;
        }
}
```

My windows Phone Application Constructor Is Setup as follows

```
 public App()
        {
            var setup = new Setup(RootFrame);
            setup.Initialize();
        }
```

But whenever setup.Initialize() is called. I get the followin exception

```
Additional information: could not load plugin assembly for type Cheesebaron.MvxPlugins.Settings.PluginLoader
   at MvvmCross.Platform.Plugins.MvxFilePluginManager.LoadAssembly(Type toLoad)
   at MvvmCross.Platform.Plugins.MvxFilePluginManager.FindPlugin(Type toLoad)
   at MvvmCross.Platform.Plugins.MvxPluginManager.ExceptionWrappedLoadPlugin(Type toLoad)
   at MvvmCross.Platform.Plugins.MvxPluginManager.EnsurePlatformAdaptionLoaded[T]()
   at Cheesebaron.MvxPlugins.Settings.PluginLoader.EnsureLoaded()
   at MvvmCross.Platform.Plugins.MvxPluginManager.EnsurePluginLoaded(IMvxPluginLoader pluginLoader)
   at MvvmCross.Platform.Plugins.MvxPluginManager.EnsurePluginLoaded(Type type)
   at MvvmCross.Platform.Plugins.MvxPluginManager.EnsurePluginLoaded[TType]()
   at MvvmCross.Platform.Plugins.MvxPluginBootstrapAction`1.Load(IMvxPluginManager manager)
   at MvvmCross.Platform.Plugins.MvxPluginBootstrapAction`1.RunAction()
   at System.Action.Invoke()
   at MvvmCross.Platform.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.InternalSetResolver(Type tInterface, IResolver resolver)
   at MvvmCross.Platform.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.RegisterSingleton[TInterface](TInterface theObject)
   at MvvmCross.Platform.Mvx.RegisterSingleton[TInterface](TInterface service)
   at MvvmCross.Core.Platform.MvxSetup.InitializePluginFramework()
   at MvvmCross.Core.Platform.MvxSetup.InitializeSecondary()
   at MvvmCross.Core.Platform.MvxSetup.Initialize()
   at IGovern.WinPhone.App..ctor()
```

Please What Am I Doing Wrong???

Comment: You are targeting Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight. It is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was targeting Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight. Turns out the the plugin does not support this platform